# Are "mother" and "father" antonyms?

Tags: terminology, lexical-semantics, lexical-relations

I think that this is not *pure* antonymy. If it's still antonymy, 
do linguists have a separate term for this type of semantic relationship?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Mother* is not the antonym of *father*. They are [co-hyponyms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypernym) because they are both a kind of *parent* - and *parent* is the hypernym of *mother* and *father*.

Antonymy is the relation that holds between *parent* and *child*. So by extension the antonym of *mother* could be said to be *child*.

EDIT: After reading hippietrail's answer, I somewhat changed my opinion. If one considers two words to be antonyms already if just one of their semantic features is replaced with the opposite then *mother* (female parent) and *father* (male parent) can be said to be antonyms. However, I feel that it might make sense to reserve antonymy for complete negation or oppositeness, and describe the relation between *mother* and *father* as hyponymy.

Comment: So male-female relationship it's always a co-hyponyms ( tiger and tigress) ? And the words "male" and "female" still antonyms paradoxically?

Comment: *Tiger* and *tigress* is more complicated because *tiger* can mean 'male tiger' and 'tiger (regardless of sex, so-called generic)'. *Tiger (male)* and *tigress* are co-hyponyms and are both a kind of *tiger (generic)*. Female and male are antonyms.

Comment: Very few words have precisely one sense, so just as with many other topics about words, when we talk of a word having an antonym, we're really talking about a specific sense having an antonym. Both *mother* and *father* have senses which are not directly related to each other.

Comment: *Parent* and *child* are also co-hyponyms. They are both kinds of *family-member*.

Comment: In the end I think it comes down to "antonym" not really being the "natural" or "God given" concept that it at first seems. As such it will be understood or analysed differently by different people. There are probably some more strictly defined technical terms to cover various more specific kinds of oppositeness. So whether it "makes sense" for you or me or all of us reading to "reserve antonymy" to a particular interpretation, we can't really ensure everybody using the word will conform to such a decree.

Answer (score 3):

I disagree with hippietrail's answer as I have not seen any dictionaries which describe this type of relationship as antonymy. For example: [father](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/father#related-to-more), [père](http://www.cnrtl.fr/antonymie/p%C3%A8re). In Merriam-webster we have ***descendant*** as antonym, and in TLFi ***enfant***.  As such, I don't think considering these types of words as antonyms is a common point of view.

In Semantics (1977, pp. 279—280), John Lyons calls this relationship [*converseness*](http://books.google.co.kr/books?id=jQA6wVLCINUC&q=converseness#v=snippet&q=converseness&f=false):

> To be distinguished from antonymy and complementarity is
>   converseness*, exemplified by pairs like 'husband' : 'wife' (which may
>   be regarded as two-place predicates). The sentence 'X is the husband
>   of Y' express a proposition whose converse is expressed by 'X is the
>   wife of Y' (cf. 6.3).
>
> Converse relations between lexemes which may be used as two-place
>   predicative expressions are especially common in areas of the
>   vocabulary having to do with reciprocal social roles
>   ('doctor' : 'patient', 'master'/'mistress' : 'servant') and kinship
>   relations ('father' : 'mother','son' : 'daughter' etc.) <...>

But in my opinion it's not applicable for lion/lioness, tiger/tigress so I don't know how to call this kind of relationship.

Comment: "I have not seen any dictionaries which describe this type of relationship as antonymy" here's one: http://thesaurus.com/browse/father

Comment: Wiktionary is another: [father / antonyms](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/father#Antonyms) ; [mother / antonyms](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Mother#Antonyms)

Comment: One of my first forays into (near-)linguistics was BBS textfiles like ["opposites" by R. Morneau](http://www.rickmor.x10.mx/opposites.html) which calls male/female for _counterparts_. The book mentioned there, **Lexical Semantics** by D.A. Cruse, Cambridge University Press, 1986, is it still worth getting? Cambridge Red Series, yes, but they do age...

Answer (score 1):

**Yes** they are antonyms. That doesn't affect whether they may have other, possibly even overlapping or seemingly contradictory relationships, such as being co-hyponyms.

Antonyms are two words which are opposites. That seems pretty simple. But in fact you have to think about what "opposite" means, and what it means for words in particular.

In the end it comes down to semantics like so many other things, and people will surely come up with multiple analyses.

- Antonyms can be adjectives naming properties: *short* vs *long*.
- They can be abstract nouns naming properties: *shortness* vs *length*.

If a property can possess a value along a scale then generally values toward each end of the scale are seen as opposites.

Then there are properties which can have one of two values, which can of course be analysed as a special case of the previous.

I'm sure some people analyse "male" and "female" to be antonyms, and people who would strongly refute it. They can certainly be argued against semantically.

If two words are nouns then they need refer to objects having one property which has "opposing" values. Some nouns have more than one property capable of this. Others have none.

Comment: My problem with considering "mother" and "father" antonyms because they differ in gender is that, unlike "male" and "female", the gender is more a secondary characteristic. Following this line of reasoning "actor" and "actress" are also antonyms, which seems wrong to me. That said, the gender *is* part of the semantics of these types of words (even if not the main point) so I do understand how one can argue this point of view.

Comment: I think the point is that it's a question where the answer is "it depends" or "it depends who you ask" or "it depends how you define your terms" or "there's more than one way to analyse it". *Actor* and *actress* are antonyms in the way *yin* and *yang* are that just doesn't work at all if you alter a different attribute like *actor* and *child actor* for want of a better example.